# How to recursively read file in a tree like directory structure in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, file

I have a root directory say "A" inside this directory i am having lots of directories say "1","2","3","4","5"........ and in all these subdirectories i have single file called cucumber.json. All i want to do is read the cucumber.json file and get the accumulated result. How can i achieve this using node js.

In the below screen shot my root directory is "cucumber" and inside that i have lot of sub directories. All these sub directories contains a single file named cucumber.json. 
[image]

Are there any dedicated node package which can make my work easy.
Let me know if any further info is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi there please try the following (javascript):

```
// Require filesystem package for IO operations
var fs = require('fs');
// Put the path you are looking for here
var path = "d:\\nodef";

//Call the function defined below
recursiveloop(path, function(err,result){
  /* begin processing of each result */
  // For each file in the array
  for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
  {
    //Write the name of the file
    console.log('Processing: ' + result[i]);
    //Read the file
    fs.readFile(result[i], 'utf8', function(err, data){
      //If there is an error notify to the console
      if(err) console.log('Error: ' + err);
      //Parse the json object
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      //Print out contents
      console.log('Name: ' + obj.name);
      console.log('Position: ' + obj.position);
    })
  }
});
// Asynchronous function to read folders and files recursively
function recursiveloop(dir, done)
{
  var results = [];
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list){
    if (err) return done(err);
    var i = 0;
    (function next() {
      var file = list[i++];
      if (!file) return done(null, results);
      file = dir + '/' + file;
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          recursiveloop(file, function(err, res) {
            results = results.concat(res);
            next();
          });
        } else {
          results.push(file);
          next();
        }
      });
    })();
  });
}
```

Comment: This could be put into a module in iteself by creating a module class and defining the recursive method like so:

module.exports = {
// Place recursiveloop function here
}

Then from the calling codefile use like so:
var recursiveloopclass = require('codefile.js')
recursiveloopclass.recursiveloop

thereby allowing for reuse

Answer (score 0):

There is an NPM module for this:

npm [dree](https://npmjs.com/package/dree)

Example:

```js
const dree = require('dree');
const options = {
    depth: 5,                        // To stop after 5 directory levels
    exclude: /dir_to_exclude/,       // To exclude some pahts with a regexp
    extensions: [ 'txt', 'jpg' ]     // To include only some extensions
};

const fileCallback = function (file) {
    action(file.path);
};

let tree;

// Doing it synchronously
tree = dree.scan('./dir', options, fileCallback);

// Doing it asynchronously (returns promise)
tree = await dree.scanAsync('./dir', options, fileCallback);

// Here tree contains an object representing the whole directory tree (filtered with options)
```